# __in Filter Does Not Work

Tags: django, django-admin-filters

I inherited a Django application that serves high school sports information. I recently received a request to modify a certain set of data so information is displayed only from the current season, which I accomplished this way:

```
teams = Team.objects.filter(season__school_year__in=school_year_filter_list)
```

(`school_year_filter_list` contains `[1,3]`)

This query causes an error in [pgpool](http://pgpool.projects.postgresql.org/) (a Postgres database pooling/replication utility) so I cannot use it. As a side note, the query works properly in the Python shell, and when I bypass pgpool and use Postgres directly. However, our network architecture dictates the use of pgpool, so I am trying to find an alternate way to retrieve the same data.

Can you help me determine another way to get all Teams with a Season in the current SchoolYear?

The (simplified) models look like this:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season)

class Season(models.Model):
    school_year = models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear, blank=True, null=True)

class SchoolYear(models.Model):
    school_year = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

The '_schoolyear' table looks like:

```
 id | school_year 
----+-------------
  1 | 2010-2011
  2 | 2009-2010
  3 | 2011-2012
```

Comment: Such a basic lookup should not cause a problem regardless of the database used. Furthermore if it is a real bug, it should be correctly identified so that it can be accounted for in Django code. It would really help if you provided details on the error caused by the lookup. I can't help but imagine that the `__in` lookup will come up again at some point, or that you're going to end up having to come up with some really weird fixes for something that shouldn't even be a problem.

Comment: @Jordan Reiter: Thank you for your feedback. We are using `__in` lookups elsewhere in the application without problem. The problem exists only with this particular query, and only with specific versions of pgpool ( 3.0.3, 3.0.4 ). We will work on developing and submitting a proper bug report later, but for now, finding a workaround is a higher priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I modified another model to make this work. Rather than parsing years to get active seasons, I added an "active" flag to the SchoolYear model and modified my query to check for that flag:

```
def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(PlayerYearAdmin, self).queryset(request)
    return qs.filter(team__season__school_year__active=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried
`teams = Team.objects.filter(season__school_year__id__in=school_year_filter_list)`
?
Isn't it right that your `school_year_filter_list` is a list of school year ids?

Comment: `school_year_filter_list` is a list of school year IDs. It is my understanding that "__id" is not required, but I tried the filter in the way you suggested, receiving the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Small note: I see 'django-admin' tag, so I think that you add season__school_year_*in=[1, 2] to URL query string like /admin/sports/team/?season*_school_year__in=[1, 2] Is it correct?

If so, are you shure that school_year_filter_list contains list `[1,3]`, but not a string containing `repr` of list `'[1,3]'`

Can you provide us data about error that pgpool or Django ORM returns?

Comment: Thank you for your response. The query filter is hard-coded in admin.py, and is not supplied via the URL. `school_year_filter_list` is definitely a list, not a string. The pgpool error is simply: 'psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed' After extensive testing, we have determined this to be a bug in the way Django communicates with pgpool, probably a driver issue.